# How to add UILabel to UICollectionView Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I created a collectionView Controller in storyboards. Everything works fine , but now i need to create UILabel in CenterX/CenterY position.

```
   @IBOutlet var routesCollectionView: UICollectionView!


    messageTextLabel.isHidden = false
    messageTextLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self. routesCollectionView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    messageTextLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self. routesCollectionView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    self.routesCollectionView.addSubview(messageTextLabel)
```

This code gives me an error. I understand that theres no view in collection view controller. Any idea how i can add this UILabel?

Comment: why is your collectionView with capital C? what is the error? have you tried adding the label before adding constraints?

Comment: Updated question. Its just a app crash

Comment: there are so many reasons an app crashes, be more specific, what error does the console prints?

Comment: You are right , i removed constraints and its ok now. Guess i should check why it is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always set constraints on a view **after** you add it as a subview.

Take a look at the console, there is probably:

> Unable to install constraint on view. Does the constraint reference
>   something from outside the subtree of the view? That's illegal.

If that is the case, make sure to add subviews **before** you anchor it.

Comment: Yup , it was the problem. I forgot that constraint should be added always after adding them to subviews.